# Inserting elements of one List To Another

Tags: asp.net, list, arraylist

I am new to programming. I am retrieving a column Price from my database and saving it into a list. I want to perform some multiplication with that data and want to store the result after multiplication into another list. Here is the code i wrote to fetch data and store it into a list.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Price from FoodPackages",con);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dataset, "FoodPackages");

            List<int> package_price = new List<int>();
            foreach(DataRow row in dataset.Tables["FoodPackages"].Rows)
            {
                package_price.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Price"]));
            }

            for( int i = 0; i<package_price.Count; i++)
            {
                int food = guest * package_price[i];  // Food = The total food cost 


            }
```

The line in which i am multiplying guest with each element of list. Here i have an integer variable but instead of this i want a list. Kindly help me do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Price from FoodPackages",con);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dataset, "FoodPackages");

List<int> package_price = new List<int>();
foreach(DataRow row in dataset.Tables["FoodPackages"].Rows)
{
       package_price.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Price"]));
}

// Initialize a new list
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for( int i = 0; i<package_price.Count; i++)
{
      int food = guest * package_price[i];  // Food = The total food cost 

      // Add element into the list
      myList.Add(food);
}
```

**ADD**: If a "guest" variable is not type of int, then you have to create List of decimal:

```
List<decimal> myList = new List<decimal>();
for( int i = 0; i<package_price.Count; i++)
{
     //int food = guest * 20;  // this line is not necessary 

     // You can calculate and add element into the list at once
     myList.Add(guest * 20);
}
```

Comment: now in this way i will have all the item after being multiplied by the guest in the new list which is myList ?

Comment: Yes, just put a break point on the last line and check what elements myList contains.

Comment: Great . thanku so much it solved my problem :) God Bless You !